# (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length)

Tags: api, flutter, dart

i have some problem with body in this code. at first there was only email and password,

```
login() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final response = await http.post(
  "https://api.batulimee.com//v1_ship/login_app",
  body:{
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
    "apikey": apikey,
  }),
);
final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
String status = data['status'];
String pesan = data['message'];
if (status == "success") {
  prefs.setString('stringValue', "apikey");
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => new bottomNavBar(),
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      transitionsBuilder:
          (_, Animation<double> animation, __, Widget child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: animation.value,
          child: child,
        );
      }));
  print(pesan);
  print(apikey);
} else {
  print(pesan);
}
}
```

and when i add apikey variable then try to login, i got an error like this.

```
Exception has occurred. NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length)
```

how should i put that apikey?

Comment: is "url" just a placeholder in the code snippet that u shared here. If url is a variable, please remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide `Map<String, String>` as body for `http.post`. It might be possible that one or more of your values is not a string. Or that the `"url"` is not an actual url.

Use the `jsonEncode()` method on your body to make sure that it is string.

```
final response =
    await http.post("url", body: jsonEncode(<String, String> {
  "email": email,
  "password": password,
  "apikey": apikey,
 }),
);
```

Before you make the post request make sure that `email`, `password` and `apikey` are not null. Try printing them to console before making the request and make sure that these does not have null values.

Please take a look at docs [Send Data to internet](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data)

**Edit**: I can't see how your `login()` method receives the values of `email`, `password` and `apikey`. In case these are the member of a class, which I am assuming, I would still check if they contain non-null values before sending a request. Your safe bet would be printing these to console just to check the contents of these variables.

```
debugPrint("Email: $email Pass: $password Key: $apikey");
```

Put this before your `http.post()` line and check if the values are null or not.

Comment: sorry, i will edit my code and resend it please take a look